# Default Excel: Finding the matching value and mentioning it in a single row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data and assignment is to arrange it in a single row using formula. Example:

[image]

```
Question) Find all the persons living in New York or Delhi?

   Sample: New York/Delhi   ________        ___________    ___________

Question) Find all the persons living in Delhi and earning more than 1200?

  Sample:  Delhi/1200   ______     ________    _________    _______
```

Please note: this data needs to be in a single row

Comment: Hello, Please read [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to properly ask questions that have a better change of receiving a positive and helpful answer. Without any detailed information about your issue, no one here can truly assist you. It also helps if you post what you have already tried. It appears that you are just asking someone to do your homework for you. Do you have some examples of what you have tried to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that name will always be of one word. So first word in the cell is *Name*, last word is *Income* and everything between name and income is *City*.

---

### **OPTION 1:**

Well, it will be better if you can split your text in three different columns as `Name`, `City` and `Income` and then use these columns to get the desired result.

To get ***Names*** from cell, enter the following formula in `Cell B2`

```
=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))
```

Then to get ***City*** use below formula in `Cell C2`

```
=TRIM(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","|",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))))-FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))
```

For ***Income***, in  `Cell D2` enter formula

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

Now in `Cell B12` enter the following formula to get results for your first query i.e.

> **Find all the persons living in New York or Delhi**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF(($C$2:$C$9="New York")+($C$2:$C$9="Delhi"), ROW($B$2:$B$9)-1, ""), COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy across as required.

And in `Cell B14` enter the following formula for your second query i.e.

> **Find all the persons living in Delhi and earning more than 1200**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF(($C$2:$C$9="Delhi")*($D$2:$D$9>1200), ROW($B$2:$B$9)-1, ""), COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1))),"")
```

Again this is an array formula. Drag/Copy across as required. See image for reference.

[image]

---

### **OPTION 2:**

If you do not want to break text in different columns then you could use following formulas to get desired results. These formulas are *pretty ugly* but will give you what you are looking for.

In `Cell B12` enter the below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT($A$2:$A$9,(FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)-1)), SMALL(IF((TRIM(MID($A$2:$A$9,FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ","|",LEN($A$2:$A$9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ",""))))-FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)-1))="New York")+(TRIM(MID($A$2:$A$9,FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ","|",LEN($A$2:$A$9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ",""))))-FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)-1))="Delhi"), ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1, ""), COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1))),"")
```

and in `Cell B14` enter

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LEFT($A$2:$A$9,(FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)-1)), SMALL(IF((TRIM(MID($A$2:$A$9,FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ","|",LEN($A$2:$A$9)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ",""))))-FIND(" ",$A$2:$A$9,1)-1))="Delhi")*(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$9," ",REPT(" ",LEN($A$2:$A$9))),LEN($A$2:$A$9)))*1>1200), ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1, ""), COLUMN(B$1)-COLUMN($A$1))),"")
```

Both above formulas are array formula so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy across as required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mirg. You made my day. Genius stuff!! Just a small doubt. Do you know how to remove duplicate values via formula? Like in above formula, how can we introduce a formula to remove duplicate values? Though I know in this case it's not relevant but just out of curiosity.

Comment: I used this function =IF(COUNTIF($B$12:B12, B12) > 1, "", B20) but it is showing space for the values that are repeated.

Comment: @Warrior92 - Well I guess I've answered your original question and I expect you to mark my solution as answer if it solved your issue. And as far your new requirement is concerned it will be fair to ask a new question with some related sample data.